# Can't block a user from a page using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/page/blocked), you can use `GET graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/blocked` endpoint to see a list of blocked users and pages from one of your pages. You can also use the POST and REMOVE methods along with `user` parameter to add or remove a user from your Page's block list.

But it seems not to be working. With the GET query and the appropriate Page Access Token, I receive a blank list just like this:

```
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MAZDZD",
      "after": "MjQZD"
    },
    "next": "----------"
  }
}
```

If I try to add some user to the block list of one of my pages, I receive this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) The global id ------- is not allowed for this call",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "-------"
  }
}
```

Why I can't see the list of blocked users and pages from my pages? And why can't I block someone: maybe I need the Page Scoped User ID? But how can I get this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you most likely need a page scoped user ID when the error message say global ID is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Do you know how to get this Page Scoped User ID? The only information I get is [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/support/psid-api), and it says the Page-Scoped ID API is deprecated in v7.0+. Nowadays, any apps created after May 1, 2018 are automatically assign PSIDs and no further action is required...

Comment: How do you get the IDs?

Comment: Oops! You are right, I was getting the User IDs from an external website, but if I get them from a Facebook App (althought is not the same app), I can create new blocked users for a page. Thanks!

But I am still not able to see the list of banned users for a page. I guess is hidden for privacy?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I am also getting a blank list of users.